# Uninstalling BizTalk 2006 R2 on Windows 7 giving an internal error 2738

Tags: biztalk, uninstallation, biztalk2006r2

I have BizTalk 2006 R2 installed on my Windows 7 machine. When trying to uninstall, I'm getting an internal error 2738. I have tried to register the vbscript dll using `regsvr32 vbscript.dll`, but that also did not resolve the problem. I ran the command prompt as an administrator.

P.S: I did see another post with the same question but found no answer. I need to uninstall the BizTalk on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

[Uninstalling Biztalk 2006 R2 on Windows 7 giving an internal error 2738](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/90adf365-f8fc-498e-b36d-b5192f2b228d/uninstalling-biztalk-2006-r2-on-windows-7-giving-an-internal-error-2738?forum=biztalkgeneral)

> I was able to resolve the problem. Apparently, the problem was not with the vbscript.dll not registered. The issue was with the vbscript dll being registered as a User instead of the machine. When the dll is registered as a normal user, it is registered under the USER in the registry settings. Removing the registration using the following command resolved the problem and I was able to uninstall Biz Talk.
>
> Command: "reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{B54F3741-5B07-11CF-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}" /f"
>
> Marked as answer by get2bidesh 8 hours 1 minutes ago

Comment: I take that this Question and answer from the above forum post were also by you?

Answer (score 1):

It worked by delete it from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}:`

```
C:\>reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}" /f
```